# Symfony DomCrawler How to search inside Javascript

Tags: php, symfony, dom, web-crawler, goutte

I'm using Goutte to grab the webpage

I use  block to find the node

```
$data = $crawler->filter('script');
```

if I want only the first node

```
$data = $crawler->filter('script')->first(); //is that right?
```

then How can I find "A LINK" ? I struck with this js block

```
<script>

   jwplayer( "clipplayer" ).setup({ 
      image: imgurl,
      playlist: [{              
          sources: [{
              bitrate: "640",
              file: "A LINK",
              label: "640SD",
              type: "video/mp4",
              provider: "video"},]                               
      }],               
      width: 728,
      height: 450,
      primary: 'flash'
   });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it just convert it to html and use preg_match_all();

Comment: how did you select the js script using `filter`? I constantly get an empty string